# Improving the speed of cell copy operations on many sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a very slow `for` loop in my Google Sheets file. There are 18 sheets for which I have to copy every cell that is greater than 0 to another sheet.

My code works for my task, but it's very slow. Perhaps someone has an idea on how to increase its speed?

Some explanation:

- I used `if` statement `if(i == 2)` because one sheet has 2700 rows
- the line `if(total.getRange(16+i, 5).getValue() > 1)` checks if sheet have 
  cells greater than zero. It prevents not testing empty sheets.

The slow part of the code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
  if (i == 2) {
    m = 2700;
  } else if (i !=  2) {
    m = 500
  }
  for (j = 9; j<m; j++) {
    if (total.getRange(16+i, 5).getValue() > 1) {
      var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(formularz.getSheets()[i]);
      if (sheet.getRange(j, 8).getValue() > 0) {
        var KOD = sheet.getRange(j, 3).getValue();
        var il = sheet.getRange(j, 8).getValue();
        wysylka.appendRow([KOD,il]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I’d probably use getValues() instead.

Comment: Yes, i used to getValues() but the lopp is still to low :(

Comment: The only way `getValues` will be slower is if you call it every step of your loop. If you do that, then you are not understanding what `getValues` is used for, and did not properly implement it. Show the code you used when you were working with `getValues`.

Comment: As your code is already working, what I can suggest is [Best Practices for Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) for optimizing the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to minimize calls to Apps Script APIs, especially within loops. Even more so within nested loops.

This is covered in the [**Using batch operations** section of the **Best Practices** documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Here's an annotated replacement that minimizes the Apps Script API calls:

*NOTE: I attempted to recreate your spreadsheet since [you didn't provide a minimal and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want to try using this, please test with a copy of your data.*

```
function replacement() {
  // For testing purposes, I created a spreadsheet that has data where 
  // your original code expects it.  I'm not sure if this is actually all 
  // in one spreadsheet or maybe spread across multiple, since you didn't
  // specify.
  var formularz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var total = formularz.getSheetByName('total');
  var wysylka = formularz.getSheetByName('wysylka');

  // CONFIGURATION

  // These are constants to capture the script configuration that can be
  // easily tweaked without diving into the code.

  // 0-based index of the first data sheet.
  var START_SHEET = 1;

  // 0-based index of the last data sheet.
  // NOTE: I only populated 3 data sheets in my test environment.
  var END_SHEET = 3;  

  // 0-based index of the row with sheet data within the total sheet.
  var TOTAL_STARTING_ROW = 16;

  // 0-based index of the column with sheet data within the total sheet.
  var TOTAL_COLUMN = 4;

  // 0-based index of the starting row within data sheets.
  var DATA_STARTING_ROW = 7;

  // 0-based index of the 'KOD' column within data sheets.
  var DATA_KOD_COLUMN = 2;

  // 0-based index of the 'il' column within data sheets.
  var DATA_IL_COLUMN = 7;

  // END OF CONFIGURATION

  // A prerequisite calculation based on the configuration.
  var numSheets = END_SHEET - START_SHEET + 1;

  // Use a single getValues() call to fetch all necessary total data.
  totalData = total.getRange(TOTAL_STARTING_ROW + 1, TOTAL_COLUMN + 1, numSheets).getValues();

  // Use an array to capture all of the rows we will append to the 'wysylka' sheet.
  var wysylkaRows = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {  
    // Use a single getValues() call to fetch all necessary data from the data sheet.
    // Using getDataRange() to get all sheet data, instead of manually keeping track
    // of number of rows per sheet.
    var sheetData = formularz.getSheets()[START_SHEET + i].getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var j = DATA_STARTING_ROW; j < sheetData.length; j++) {
      if (totalData[i][0] > 1) {
        if (sheetData[j][DATA_IL_COLUMN] > 0) {
          // Push an array that represents a row we'll add to the 'wysylka' sheet.
          wysylkaRows.push([
            sheetData[j][DATA_KOD_COLUMN],
            sheetData[j][DATA_IL_COLUMN]
          ]);                  
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Get a range for all of the accumulated rows.
  appendRange = wysylka.getRange(wysylka.getLastRow() + 1, 1,
                                 wysylkaRows.length, wysylkaRows[0].length);
  // Set all rows with a single setValues() call.
  appendRange.setValues(wysylkaRows);
}
```

As noted, in my testing I only populated 3 data sheets (instead of 17). I was able to process ~1000 rows of data in a 1.034 seconds.

Comment: OP didn't ask a good enough question to get a nearly turn-key solution (you even reference this fact in your answer). My analysis is that OP doesn't know how to work with JavaScript arrays. A simple example of using `getValues` and `getDataRange` would help OP learn more. It is good that you included links to reference documentation though.

Comment: Point taken. My intention with the comments throughout the code was to provide pointers on the various optimizations. Will rethink my approach in future answers. Thanks!